# How to get colored output in Mac terminal?

Tags: ssh, mac, terminal, colors

I recently tried to connect to a server via SSH using the Mac Terminal and ran the HTOP command, but the output was completely monochrome. I searched online for a solution, but couldn't find a way to enable colored output in the Mac Terminal. I also attempted using the Hyper terminal application, but ultimately had to resort to Putty on virtualized Windows.

I'm wondering if there is a straightforward method to enable color output in the Mac Terminal by default. I find it puzzling why this functionality is not readily available. Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.